# ¿Cómo se extrae la mitad de un array en c#?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

`int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }`

Tengo este array y tengo una pequeña idea de lo que hay que hacer, comprendo que he de sacar la mitad del tamaño del array para poner imprimir la mitad del mismo pero de ahí en adelante me pierdo bastante, en otros lenguajes sé que existía slice o splice pero soy super nuevo en c# y más perdido no podría estar, me sería de gran utilidad si me ayudasen con esto.

Comment: siquiera lo buscaste en google??? porque existe exactamente con ese nombre y tiene un ejemplo hermoso en la MSDN...

Comment: Si no quieres una copia de los elementos, puedes usar un [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.span-1)

Answer (score 2):

El metodo [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0) te retorna la lista de elementos hasta el indice indicado:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
var elementos = array.Take(array.Length / 2);
```

En tu caso solo es de dividir el tamano del array entre 2 y tendras la mitad de los elementos.

Comment: tabien existe slice (para un ArraySegment) lo cual hace que la pregunta tenga absolutamente 0 de investigacion ;)

Comment: Tuvo horas de investigación pero claramente tú tienes 0 horas de investigación sobre cómo hay gente neurodivergente a la que estas cosas le cuestan, las soluciones que encontraba no me cuadraban con lo que buscaba pero me esforcé, no habría venido aquí si hubiese encontrado lo que buscaba en mdsn, solo soy un novato que a veces tiene las respuestas obvias en la cara pero le cuesta y aún así quiere aprender, gracias de todos modos por la respuesta pero a ver si usas la investigación para encontrar algo de empatia o amabilidad que eso no te sobra precisamente.

Comment: Estimado/a @KaiMontaña antes que te frustes, lee las siguientes recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 te ayudará a formular preguntas sólidas con mínima chance de obtener comentarios relacionados al tema de investigar. En tu pregunta dices `y tengo una pequeña idea de lo que hay que hacer` y seguido colocas lo que deberías hacer, lo cual me parece genial, toma unas guías: https://www.dotnetperls.com/ + https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/csharpya/ + https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm Sé que te será de utilidad.

Comment: Hmm... @KaiMontaña, Generalmente los usuarios del sitio son de esa misma opinión; y no es por no querer ayudar, más bien sabemos que la investigación es lo que te dará de comer. Si no investigas y esperas que otras personas resuelvan tus dudas, tus probabilidades de éxito son bajas. Tómalo por el lado amable. La investigación va primero. Podrías haber llegado tú mismo a la respuesta, y quizás aprendido más si hubieses investigado aunque sea un poco

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/ -> En español.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar [Rangos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) para obtener una sub lista

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
int mitad = array.Length / 2; //obtenemos la cantidad que es la mitad
var PrimeraMitad = array[..mitad]; //es lo mismo que largo array[0..mitad]
var SegundaMitad = array[mitad..]; //es lo mismo que largo array[mitad..array.Length]
```